# Send UImages in email as pdf

Tags: ios, email, pdf, uiimage

I have 10 images that are collected and imported into email and the user will send the images but they keep showing up as attachments and I need the images to be one behind the other and not as attachments. I was thinking of a pdf but I don't know how to generate one...

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Contents Concepts Photo report"];

        [mailer.view setNeedsDisplay];


        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ContentsConceptsLogoFinal6copy" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];


        NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path1];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData1 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];



        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNail.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imageone"];


        NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path2];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData2 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];

        NSData *imageDatatwo = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatatwo mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagetwo"];

        NSString *path3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path3];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData3 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];

        NSData *imageDatathree = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailthree.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatathree mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagethree"];

        NSString *path4 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"4" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData4 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path4];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData4 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];

        NSData *imageDatafour = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailfour.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatafour mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagefour"];

        NSString *path5 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"5" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData5 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path5];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData5 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];

        NSData *imageDatafive = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailfive.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatafive mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagefive"];


        NSString *path6 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"6" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData6 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path6];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData6 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];


        NSData *imageDatasix = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailsix.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatasix mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagesix"];
        NSString *path7 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"7" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData7 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path7];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData7 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];
        NSData *imageDataseven = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailseven.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDataseven mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imageseven"];
        NSString *path8 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"8" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData8 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path8];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData8 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];
        NSData *imageDataeight = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNaileight.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDataeight mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imageeight"];

        NSString *path9 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"9" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData9 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path9];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData9 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];

        NSData *imageDatanine = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailnine.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDatanine mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imagenine"];
        NSString *path10 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10" ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *myData10 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path10];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData10 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"photo name"];
        NSData *imageDataten = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.personimgThumbNailten.image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageDataten mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Imageten"];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ios-tricks.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-create-pdf-file-from-array-of.html

Comment: Why wouldn't the images appear as attachments? You are adding them as attachments.

Comment: becuase i need them to show up in a report style.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I can come up with is if you compile the images into one PDF, and attach the PDF. More on that here-

```
-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:   (NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: I dont know how this fits into my code i tried entering it and its not working...

Comment: Hold on. You want the PDF to be an attachment right @mattsuff

Comment: So then you do the above, and then use the inbuilt Mail client to attach it to a mail and sent!  @mattsuff